# Issue with Spring, JPA, and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0

I am using spring and hibernate to develop a simple online auction system. I have created a POJO "Items.java" which contains data variables like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="item_id")
private Integer itemId;

@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String summary;

@Column
private double price;

@Column
private String description;

@Column(name="sDate", insertable=false, updatable=false, columnDefinition="timestamp default current_timestamp")
@Generated(value=GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private  Date sDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date cDate;
```

`sDate` and `cDate` are starting date and closing date respectively. `sDate` is the current date which is inserted automatically and `cDate` is closing date which will be input by the seller through the form. So, I am trying to insert (name,summary,price,description and closing date)to mysql by taking input from the seller using JSP form. All the data gets inserted except the date. The date value is NULL in the database. Why is it so?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I searched a lot for this problem but could not get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you have "Insertable = false" in the @Column annotation for the date.

```
boolean insertable
(Optional) Whether the column is included in SQL INSERT statements generated by the persistence provider.
Default value:
true
Since:
JPA 1.0
```

Ref: http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Column

Try removing it.

Comment: Hi Thanx for the reply. but i am talking about cDate not sDate. sDate is fine and current time stamp gets inserted into mysql automatically but the sDate whose value is obtained from the jsp form (e.g. the seller enters (name,summary,price,description,bid closing date), so this closing date/cDate is not being inserted). I think while getting data from the form, the date value is in string format and is not being converted to DATETIME format, but how can i convert it in spring Controller class ??

Answer (score 1):

When setting `insertable=false`, you must somehow provide the value for this column by means of database mechanisms like a trigger in Oracle or a default value. The application code won't generate the timestamp for you.